# Can't Resolve Libraries on Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I need to implement design Library

My Project Can't resolve any of .support Libraries or any android libraries only Accept androidx Libraries
[image: This Image Show the Problem]

Comment: Please paste the problematic code in code tags, do not post it as a screenshot.

Comment: The `android.support` classes are all deprecated, no longer receiving bug fixes or new features, and should not be used in new code.  You should [migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Answer is Go the Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX and it will automatically Solve the Problem.